# Hibernate ManytoMany update

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one relation many to many on my sql

[image]

and here is my 2 entities media and genre

```
@Entity(name = "genre")
public class Genre_entity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int genre_id;
    @Column(name="genre_Nom")
    private String genre_name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "genres", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<Media_entity> medias = new HashSet<>();

@Entity(name="media")
public class Media_entity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer media_id;

    @Column(name = "media_Titre")
    private String media_title;

    @Column(name = "media_AnneeSortie")
    private Integer media_year;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="typeMedia_Id")
    private MediaType_entity mediaType;

    @Column(name = "valid")
    private boolean media_valid ;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name =  "media_genre",
            joinColumns  = {@JoinColumn(name="media_Id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="genre_Id")}
            )
    private Set<Genre_entity> genres = new HashSet<>();
```

Its running without problem until when i want to edit the table "media_genre" . i got this error

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: entity.Genre_entity
```

here is my test code

```
public void editFilm(Integer id, String mediaTitle , Integer mediaYear, String[] listGenre) {
            Session session = null;
            Transaction tx = null;

            try {
                session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
                tx = session.beginTransaction();
                Media_entity media = getMediaByIdSimple(id);
                media.setMedia_title(mediaTitle);
                media.setMedia_year(mediaYear);

                for (String str : listGenre) {
                    Genre_entity genre = new Genre_entity();
                    genre.setGenre_name(str);
                    media.addGenre(genre);  
                }
                session.merge(media);
                tx.commit();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (tx != null) {
                    tx.rollback();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                if(session != null) {
                    session.close();
                }
            }

        }
```

I just want to edit this table "media_genre" without changing those 2 entities media and genre .

Thanks

Comment: You execute a merge. Try adding `CascadeType.MERGE` to the `cascade`. --- A remark on your code: `Media_entity` is an... unusual class name. I would recommend renaming the class to `Media` and move it in a (sub-)package `entity`

Comment: Thanks for your help , i have tried with cascade.Merge , Persist , and ALL before but still got the same problem. and my class is always on sub package Entity , its just my convention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the way that make Hibernate just insert the new update to my table association media_genre without insert or required new insert to my table entity genre.
I just load my old object genre which are already existed in my database in place creat new object then i added the new collection to this object . With that Hibernate insert only the new collections into my table media_genre only. here is the code complete

```
public void editFilm(Integer id, String mediaTitle , Integer mediaYear, String[] listGenre) {
            Session session = null;
            Transaction tx = null;
            Genre_entity genre = null;
            try {
                session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
                tx = session.beginTransaction();
                Media_entity media = getMediaByIdSimple(id);
                media.setMedia_title(mediaTitle);
                media.setMedia_year(mediaYear);
                for (String str : listGenre) {
                    Query<Genre_entity> q = session.createQuery("select g from genre g where g.genre_name = ?0", Genre_entity.class);
                    q.setParameter(0, str);
                    genre = q.getSingleResult();
                    genre.setGenre_name(str);
                    media.addGenre(genre);  
                }
                tx.commit();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (tx != null) {
                    tx.rollback();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                if(session != null) {
                    session.close();
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your solution but, just to help with the first error you reported:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: entity.Genre_entity
```

I think it's because you are merging the media object without saving genre object first. You have to save Genre object (supposing that it will be a new record in database) and then merge Media object.

Comment: Thanks to much for your help , but its not my problem , the problem was edit the association table Media_Genre without creat the new object Genre or Media, i dont need to creat the new record on my table genre or media.